# Where is the best place to put a value which is computed once by the initial passed-in parameter and never changed again, in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a reactjs component, I will compute a value based on the passed-in parameter, which will never changed again.

Say:

```
React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.computedValue = complexComputing(this.props.feed);
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>{this.computedValue}</div>
    }
});
```

You can see I've put the `computedValue` into `this` directly, but I'm not sure if it's the best place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb is render should be derived from props and state.  Because you can't change your props, I'd put it in state.

```
React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.setState({
            computedValue: complexComputing(this.props.feed)
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>{this.state.computedValue}</div>
    }
});
```

Putting things on `this` is correct if you just want to share data between lifecycle methods, most commonly to make things available for cleanup in componentWillUnmount.

Comment: A good point: `render should be derived from props and state`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're in one of the right methods for these types of computations.

According to a React components life cycle there is a few methods that only gets invoked once and only once and they are `getInitialState()`, `getDefaultProps()`, `componentWillMount()` and `componentDidMount()`.

I would however put it in `getDefaultProps()` since it makes more sense to have this type of data there since it's data that you *don't* want to mutate via state.

Comment: The computed data I want is based on the passed-in properties, is it possible to get that in `getDefaultProps`?

Comment: And also, from the spec:  `In addition, be aware that any complex objects returned by getDefaultProps() will be shared across instances, not copied`. The computed value I want is just immutable for the owner instance, it should not be shared.