# store data temporarily in a component without using state

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that queries a local http point and returns data every few seconds. Each time the ajax request returns, I package some of the info returned into an object and add that object to an array. This means that each time the ajax call returns, I have to

1. get the array from state
2. add the new array to state after I add the object to the array

As a result of this continuously updating of state, my React app renders automatically (& unnecessarily). Nothing has changes in the UI as a result of adding to the object to the array (and then storing the array in state) but React renders automatically.

Question: Is there a way to have an array accessible to different function calls in a component without using state?

```
  var arr = this.state.arrayOfObjects.slice();
  obj = {};
  var timeStamp = Date.now();
  obj['stuffFromApi'] = apiStuff;
  obj['timeStamp'] = timeStamp;
  arr.push(obj);    
  this.setState({ arrayOfObjects: arr});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the best place to put a value which is computed once by the initial passed-in parameter and never changed again, in ReactJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338913/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-a-value-which-is-computed-once-by-the-initial-pas)

Comment: I also guess that maybe you should/could use Flux, that way a store could decide whether or not it should update your component state, thus, trigger a render call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an instance variable:

```
this.arrayOfObjects = this.arrayOfObjects || []; // can also be initialized in componentWillMount method.
obj = {};
var timeStamp = Date.now();
obj['stuffFromApi'] = apiStuff;
obj['timeStamp'] = timeStamp;
this.arrayOfObjects.push(obj);
```

Then you can access `this.arrayOfObjects` from other functions too.